# How to get the Tinted kind of effect for a view in android

Tags: android

I am trying to display the view in two different types based on the item selected

***State:***

[image]

---

***I have the xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <utils.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chkBx"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:background="@drawable/slected"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

- For the tick mark in `state`, I am able to show it using `chkBx`
  view, I am loading image using `img`

### How to show the tinted view in `state`

`Programatically` or in `xml`

Comment: how about setting  `android:src ="@drawable/slected"`  to the ImageView and using something like `android:background = "#55000000"` ?

Answer (score 0):

if you set tint programatically it will work for <21 versions as well:

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable), getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));
```